# There are 5 different pairs of gloves, where left and right are distinguishable.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways are there to randomly select 4 gloves from five pairs of gloves such that some 2 of the 4 make a pair?

My answer is $(5 \times 8 \times 7)/2 = 140$. According to the site I am learning, the answer is 130. They give a different method of solution to what I come up with and I would like to understand how to correct my method.

So I said the following: you can choose a pair five ways and have two places to fill

$$LRXX$$

we can choose eight for the first $X$ and seven for the last $X$. We have to divide by 2 for order. That is, it does not matter.

I think that I need to subtract 10 from my 140 because I am counting two pairs of gloves. We are just after 4 gloves of which contain one pair

$$R_1 L_1 R_2 L_2,R_1 L_1 R_3 L_3, ...$$

There are $4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10$ ways of writing this.

I think this corrects my solution appropriately. Even thought I have reached the correct answer I could just be blowing smoke.

Comment: Your method overcounts the selections that have more than one pair.  You count those selections twice.  There are $\binom 52=10$ ways to choose two pairs.

Comment: To be clear, this is not a good way to count.  It happens that, in this particular case, it's easy to see the selections that are multiply counted and it is easy to correct for the error.  But, usually, this method badly overcounts in all sorts of ways and correcting for all the different errors is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Ok. So my correction is correct? I'm really interested in combinatorics and counting problems so it would be great if you could expand on what you mean by this is not a good way to count?

Comment: By fixing the pair and assigning the others randomly, you over count the selections with multiple pairs.  If your selection had $k$ pairs, you would count it $k$ times. Here, the numbers are so small that $k$ has to be $1$ or $2$, not a big deal.  But if $k$ could be $30$ you'd have to analyze each case separately.

Comment: You can see how your counting method can be fixed in my answer below (see the parts highlighted in bold). However, as @lulu mentioned, applying your counting method especially for Case 2 is tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"some 2 of the 4 make a pair", it means that we can have one pair and two distinct gloves or two pairs, right?

We can reach this answer by calculating (all selections - not any pair gloves)

So, $$\binom{10}{4}-\binom{5}{4}2^4=210-80=130$$

In other way, select (two pairs) or (select only one pair and two distincts) $$\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}2^2=10+120=130$$

Answer (score 1):

Taking "some two pairs" to mean at least one pair, we can simply compute it as {All slections} - {No pair selections}
$$= \dfrac{(10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7)-(10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4)}{4!} = 130$$

Answer (score 0):

Two cases can be considered. I show how your counting method can be corrected in each case.

**Case 1:**

If only a single pair is allowed in the 4 selected gloves, the answer is 120 (neither 130 nor 140):

$$\binom{5}{1} \binom {4}{2} 2^2 = 120. $$

**Your method** can be corrected as

$$5×(8×\boldsymbol{6})/2=120$$

When you pick a glove from the 8 remaining gloves (say $R_2$), for the next glove you have 6 choices (you cannot select $L_2$ because you already picked $R_2$).

**Case 2:**

If at least a pair is required in the 4 selected gloves, the answer is 130:

$$\binom{5}{1} \binom {4}{2} 2^2 + \binom{5}{2}= 130. $$

**Your method** can be corrected as

$$5×(8×\boldsymbol{6})/2+\boldsymbol{\frac{5×(8×1)/2}{2}}=130.$$

Note that when the second pair is selected, in $(8×1)/2$ possible ways, another (somehow hidden) order between the first and second pairs must be removed.